# Populate JTable Using List

Tags: java, swing, list, jtable

How will I populate a JTable with values from a List with an Object Type.
My Code looks like this :

```
String[] columnNames = {"CLASS CODE",
        "TIME",
        "DAY",
        "ROOM",
        "PROFESSOR"};

    List<org.mine.ScheduleAttr> schedule = getStudSched(studNo);
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    table.setModel(model);

    model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
```

I already have the columns, the list would come  from the schedule variable ? How can I put that to my table considering these columns ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html). You could iterate over your List and create the Object array for each row.

```
for (ScheduleAttr s : schedule) {
  Object[] o = new Object[5];
  o[0] = s.getX();
  o[1] = s.getY();
  o[2] = s.getZ();
  o[3] = s.getA();
  o[4] = s.getB();
  model.addRow(o);
}
```

Comment: The link DefaultTableModel is deprecated

Comment: I just fixed the link, @Fred37b

Answer (score 6):

You could use something similar to (just changing `columns` and `values`):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class TestJFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestJFrame testJFrame = new TestJFrame();

        List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String[]> values = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        columns.add("col1");
        columns.add("col2");
        columns.add("col3");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            values.add(new String[] {"val"+i+" col1","val"+i+" col2","val"+i+" col3"});
        }

        TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(values.toArray(new Object[][] {}), columns.toArray());
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        testJFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        testJFrame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        testJFrame.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        testJFrame.setVisible(true);
        testJFrame.setSize(200,200);
    }

}
```

The `columns` doesn't need to look like `columns.toArray()` because you already have an array of objects, so is just use it. At the end in order to use your columns the instruction  looks like:
`TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(values.toArray(new Object[][] {}), columnNames);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

first make a iterator

```
Iterator itr = StringList.iterator();



 while(itr.hasNext()) {
                 Object element = itr.next();
                     int y=0;
                     for (y=0; y <=16 ; y++){
                    table_4.setValueAt(element, y, 0);
```

table_4 is your table name then set the row and column where you want to insert the string