# Adding values from a List<Class> to Jtable

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

Hello my problem is the foloowing i have a List of a certain class of which i want to bind the values to a jtable (order in which they are added isnt important right now)
The class that is in the list is as folows

```
public HighScore(int score, int amountofplayers, String playerName,String dateString) {
    this.score = score;
    this.amountofplayers = amountofplayers;
    this.playerName = playerName;
    this.dateString = dateString;
}
```

the function that returns the list is

```
   public ArrayList<HighScore> GetHighScores()
{
    ArrayList<HighScore> highscores = new ArrayList<HighScore>();
    //get highscores from databse

    //insert some test values
    highscores.add(new HighScore(125, 2, "Piet","20-10-2015"));
    highscores.add(new HighScore(167, 2, "Henk", "19-10-2015"));
    highscores.add(new HighScore(278, 2, "Jan", "11-10-2015"));
    return highscores;
}
```

So now i want to add all these highscores to my Jtable1 in which resides in a jpannel. What would be the easiest/most effiecient way to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate JTable Using List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095802/populate-jtable-using-list)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to create a JTable object, the simplest way is to use one of its constructors.

There are two JTable constructors that directly accept data (`SimpleTableDemo` uses the first):

```
JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)
JTable(Vector rowData, Vector columnNames)
```

`rowData` must have your objects in the position you want them to be shown. For instance, to obtain the object in the first column of the second row, JTable will execute `rowData[1][0]` (it follows the form `rowData[row][col]`).

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom `TableModel` to hold your HighScore objects.

Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/). It will show you how to either:

1. Create a custom TableModel from scratch
2. Use a generic TableModel and just implement a couple of methods to reflect the data of your HighScore object.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a DefautTableModel, creating a instance of it. Then use a for loop passing your highscores to an Object[], then adding rows with the DefautTableModel addRow method.

Check [Populate JTable Using List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095802/populate-jtable-using-list) C12-H22-O11 answer for an example