# CSV to table in Java

Tags: java, csv

I looking for way to put data from CSV file to table. 
I have problem with refresh rate. Table print out just one row.
How do I change this code to print more rows in table?
Because in CSV file I have for example 20 or more rows.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class FileParser {
    String aFileToRead = "";

    public FileParser(String aNameOfFile) {
        this.aFileToRead = aNameOfFile;
    }

    public void readFileToObjects() {
        int comma1=0;
        int comma2=0;
        int comma3=0;
        int comma4=0;
        int comma5=0;
        int comma6=0;
        int comma7=0;
        int comma8=0;
        int comma9=0;
        int comma10=0;
        int comma11=0;
        int comma12=0;
        int comma13=0;
        int comma14=0;
        int comma15=0;
        int endOfLine=0;
        double aTemperature = 0.0;
        double aHumidity = 0.0;
        double aPressure = 0.0;
        double aOrientation_x = 0.0;
        double aOrientation_y = 0.0;
        double aOrientation_z = 0.0;
        double aMagnetic_x = 0.0;
        double aMagnetic_y = 0.0;
        double aMagnetic_z = 0.0;
        double aSpeed_x = 0.0;
        double aSpeed_y = 0.0;
        double aSpeed_z = 0.0;
        String aGyroscope_x = "";
        String aGyroscope_y = "";
        String aGyroscope_z = "";
        String aTime = "";
        String chartPositionAsString="";
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();


        try {
            String aStr = null;
            FileInputStream aFile = new FileInputStream(this.aFileToRead);
            InputStreamReader aInReader = new InputStreamReader(aFile);
            BufferedReader theBufReader = new BufferedReader(aInReader);
            while ((aStr = theBufReader.readLine()) != null) {
                comma1 = aStr.indexOf(",");
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(0, comma1);
                aTemperature = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma2 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma1 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma1 + 1, comma2);
                aHumidity = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma3 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma2 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma2 + 1, comma3);
                aPressure = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma4 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma3 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma3 + 1, comma4);
                aOrientation_x = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma5 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma4 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma4 + 1, comma5);
                aOrientation_y = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma6 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma5 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma5 + 1, comma6);
                aOrientation_z = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma7 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma6 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma6 + 1, comma7);
                aMagnetic_x = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma8 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma7 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma7 + 1, comma8);
                aMagnetic_y = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma9 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma8 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma8 + 1, comma9);
                aMagnetic_z = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma10 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma9 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma9 + 1, comma10);
                aSpeed_x = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma11 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma10 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma10 + 1, comma11);
                aSpeed_y = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma12 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma11 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma11 + 1, comma12);
                aSpeed_z = Double.parseDouble(chartPositionAsString);

                comma13 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma12 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma12 + 1, comma13);
                aGyroscope_x = (chartPositionAsString);

                comma14 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma13 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma13 + 1, comma14);
                aGyroscope_y = (chartPositionAsString);

                comma15 = aStr.indexOf(",", comma14 + 1);
                chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma14 + 1, comma15);
                aGyroscope_z = (chartPositionAsString);

                endOfLine = aStr.length();
                aTime = chartPositionAsString = aStr.substring(comma15 + 1, endOfLine);

               Env aEnv = new Env(aTemperature, aHumidity, aPressure, 
                                  aOrientation_x, aOrientation_y, aOrientation_z, 
                                  aMagnetic_x, aMagnetic_y, aMagnetic_z, aSpeed_x, aSpeed_y, aSpeed_z, 
                                  aGyroscope_x, aGyroscope_y, aGyroscope_z,
                                  aTime);

               String columnNames1[] = { "Temperature", "Humidity", "Pressure",
                    "Orientation yaw", "Orientation pitch", "Orientation roll", 
                       "Magnetic X", "Magnetic Y", "Magnetic Z",
                       "Speed X", "Speed Y", "Speed Z",
                       "Gyroscope X", "Gyroscope Y", "Gyroscope Z",
                       "Time" };    

                Object[][] rowData1 = {
                          {aEnv.getTemperature(), aEnv.getHumidity(), aEnv.getPressure(),
                           aEnv.getOrientation_x(), aEnv.getOrientation_y(), aEnv.getOrientation_z(), 
                           aEnv.getMagnetic_x(), aEnv.getMagnetic_y(), aEnv.getMagnetic_z(), 
                           aEnv.getSpeed_x(), aEnv.getSpeed_y(), aEnv.getSpeed_z(), 
                           aEnv.getGyroscope_x(), aEnv.getGyroscope_y(), aEnv.getGyroscope_z(),
                           aEnv.getTime(),}};

                JTable table = new JTable(rowData1, columnNames1);
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
                table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));

                frame.add((Component) scrollPane, "Center");  

                frame.setTitle("Enviromental Data");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
                frame.setSize(1900, 100);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("The File is Not in The Correct Directory");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: rather than re-invent the wheel try using something like csvreader

Comment: Your code looks very repetitive. Perhaps you want an array and a loop?

Comment: BTW you have the creation of your JTable within your while loop - meaning that it will get re-created for each row

Comment: Yes I was thinking to put comma or chartPositionAsString to arrey.

Comment: I want to simplify this also. But my mayor problem is to print out in table
So its get refresh when new data go to CSV. Cos this run on Raspberry Pi.
Python get data to csv from Sense Hat and Java display this in table.

Comment: @Tom did you just thought about split your line on `,`, I don't see any update on the data so you just need to split the line and add the String[] into the JTable. No need of CSVReader in that simple case.

Comment: @Tom, with a simple code to read entire file, are you able to read all the lines of the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a lot of variable for nothing.

```
List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
while ((aStr = theBufReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] dataLine = aStr.split(",");
    rows.add(dataLine);
}
```

Then, create the JTable, you probably going to need to recreate the `Object[][]` from the list. Or see this to [Populate JTable Using List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095802/populate-jtable-using-list)

If you really need to convert some row to number (for formatting), you can use a loop to convert those columns, using an array containing the column index and loop only on those.